# Google Analytics code inline inside "OnClick"

Tags: google-analytics

So I want to send link inside email and track clicks.
Is it possible to add Google Analytics code inline inside "OnClick":

```
    `<a href="#" onClick="

    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-12341234-1', 'auto');
    ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    ga('send', 'event', 'website', 'payment', 'from-email', { 'hitCallback': function() { document.location = 'http://www.example.com/'; }});

    ">
    Buy item</a>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this will not work. Most email clients either do not run JavaScript or strictly control what kinds of scripts are allowed to run.

The best way to track button clicks from an email is to add custom campaign parameters to the button's URL such as `utm_source`, `utm_medium`, `utm_campaign`, etc.

Here's some more information on creating and using custom campaigns in Google Analytics:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en